# How to play audio in xamarin forms?

Tags: audio, xamarin.forms

I am trying to play an audio file which is stored locally. I am using `Xam.Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer` for playing audio. For UWP and Android, added the files in the Assets folder with the Build Action set to Content and Android Asset respectively.

My Code:

```
private void PlayAudio()
    {
        try
        {
            var stream = GetStreamFromFile("audio.mp3");
            var audio = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
            audio.Load(stream);
            audio.Play();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("exception:>>" + e);
        }
    }

    Stream GetStreamFromFile(string filename)
    {
        var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

        var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("AudioPlay." + filename);

        return stream;
    }
```

But getting an exception in android and UWP, didn't check in IOS.

Android Exception:

> [0:] exception:>>System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>     at Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.SimpleAudioPlayerImplementation.Load (System.IO.Stream audioStream) [0x00050] in C:\dev\open\Xamarin-Plugins\SimpleAudioPlayer\SimpleAudioPlayer\Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.Android\SimpleAudioPlayerImplementation.cs:100 
>     at AudioPlay.MainPage.PlayAudio () [0x00014] in F:\AudioPlay\AudioPlay\AudioPlay\MainPage.xaml.cs:63

I am using .mp3 file. Am I missing something in this implementation? Please help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to directly put the mp3 file in share project . And call the method

```
var stream = GetStreamFromFile("xxx.mp3");
var audio = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
audio.Load(stream );
audio.Play();
```

```
Stream GetStreamFromFile(string filename)
{
   var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

   var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("yourprojectname." + filename);

   return stream;
}
```

### Update

I check your demo , and if you want to play mp3 file in your project. You need to set the build action of the mp3 as **Embedded resource**

Right click the mp3 file -> **Property**

[image]

Comment: The name 'GetStreamFromFile' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Provide the sample and I will test it on my side.

Comment: Can you please have a look, I have uploaded a sample on google folder.

Comment: Again getting exception: [0:] exception:>>System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.SimpleAudioPlayerImplementation.Load (System.IO.Stream audioStream) [0x00050] in C:\dev\open\Xamarin-Plugins\SimpleAudioPlayer\SimpleAudioPlayer\Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.Android\SimpleAudioPlayerImplementation.cs:100 
  at AudioPlay.MainPage.PlayAudio () [0x00014] in F:\AudioPlay\AudioPlay\AudioPlay\MainPage.xaml.cs:63 
09-27 16:25:00.759 V/MediaPlayer(13226): resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgr

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200066/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-sreejith-sree).

Comment: One quick question, I moved the sounds into a folder created on the PCL project. Then I use like below in code. The folder name is `sounds`.
 var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("yourprojectname.sounds" + filename); But sounds is not playing. Also tried var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("yourprojectname/sounds." + filename);

Comment: var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("yourprojectname." + filename);

Answer (score 0):

try this For xamarin.android

```
var u = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("filepath");
MediaPlayer _player = MediaPlayer.Create(this, u);
_player.Start();
```

or
use XamarinMediaManager plugin

https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager

Comment: What "filepath" tho? "Resources.Drawable.Audio"?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer does not work when attempting to load a resource from a project that is not the main Xamarin Forms project.

The solution is to use [`Android.AssetManager.Open()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.content.res.assetmanager.open?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9) to get a `Stream` *(I'm sure iOS has something similar)*. You'll need to use [`DependencyService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to access this outside the Android project.

The MP3 files would be put in the Assets folder of the Android project. **The audio files need to have Build Action: "Android Asset"**, not "Embedded Resource" as above.

---

Example:
Android Project has `Assets/Audio/click.mp3`

AndroidProject/AndroidAssetManager.cs

```
[assembly: Dependency (typeof (AndroidAssetManager))]
namespace App.Droid
{
    public interface IAssetManager
    {
        Stream LoadAsset(string assetName);
        ...
    }

    public class AndroidAssetManager : IAssetManager
    {
        private readonly AssetManager _assets;

        public AndroidAssetManager(AssetManager assets)
        {
            _assets = assets;
        }
        
        public Stream LoadAsset(string assetName)
        {
            return _assets.Open(assetName);
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Shared/AudioPlayer.cs:

```
class AudioPlayer : IAudioPlayer
{
    private IAssetManager AssetManager => DependencyService.Get<IAssetManager>();
    private ISimpleAudioPlayer _clickPlayer;

    public AudioPlayer()
    {
        _clickPlayer = CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.CreateSimpleAudioPlayer();
        _clickPlayer.Load(AssetManager.Load("Audio/click.mp3"));
    }

    public void PlayClick()
    {
        _clickPlayer.Play();
    }
}
```