# Play .wav audio in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to play an .wav audio file, for which I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58130631).

I followed this answer but I get an error message on `audio.Load(stream);` says `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

To me it seems that the problem is that, `audio.load()` couldn't find the audio file, which is in `Resource/raw` path.

**Complete Code**

```
private void Counter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer_countdown = new Timer();
    timer_countdown.Interval = 1000;
    timer_countdown.Elapsed += OnTimedEventIDCamera;
    timer_countdown.Enabled = true;
    timer_countdown.AutoReset = true;
    timer_countdown.Start();
}

private void OnTimedEventIDCamera(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Seconds++;

    if (Seconds == 3)
    {
        var stream = GetStreamFromFile("beepSound.wav");
        var audio = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
        audio.Load(stream);
        audio.Play();
    }
}

Stream GetStreamFromFile(string filename)
{
    var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

    var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("yourprojectname." + filename);

    return stream;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: have you checked if `stream` is null?

Comment: I added the audio file in `resources/raw` directory as told in the answer linked above

Comment: @DourHighArch no.. I looked into it.. nothing helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your description and code, you have one audio file in Android platform Resource/raw folder. If you use the code you provide above, you can not get audio file and stream is null.

You can put .wav audio file in **Forms shared** and setting **Build Action** to **Embedded Resource**

```
 private void Btnwav(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var stream = GetStreamFromFile("xxx.wav");
        var audio = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
        audio.Load(stream);
        audio.Play();
    }
    Stream GetStreamFromFile(string filename)
    {
        var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

        var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("yourprojectname." + filename);

        return stream;
    }
```

**Update:**

My project name is playvideo, add minions.mp4

```
 private void Btnwav(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var stream = GetStreamFromFile("minions.mp4");
        var audio = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
        audio.Load(stream);
        audio.Play();
    }
    Stream GetStreamFromFile(string filename)
    {
        var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

        var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("playvideo." + filename);

        return stream;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for response. what do u mean by **Forms shared**? how to put file in Forms shared? and this `yourprojectname.` will be different for my project?

Comment: @Tarkovsky Please see my update code and image. The Forms shared is .Net standard library project(shared code).

Comment: @Tarkovsky I have updated my reply, please take a look.