# the system cannot find the file specified error when i add sound file to xamarin forms project

Tags: android, audio, xamarin.forms

[image]

I add this bip.wav file to Assets folder and i got this the system cannot find the file specified error.

[image]

I delete the sound file then clean solution and rebuild solution. After all that processes my app works.
So, i can not add a sound file to project.

This is my code to play sound.

```
var player = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current; player.Load("bip.wav"); player.Play();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you added the file in to the Asset folder of the Android part, you need to set the **Build Action** for this file to **AndroidAsset**. And then use the `AssetManager` to read the file. And `AssetManager` can be only used the android project. So you can use the [Xamarin.Forms DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/) to call this api for the android.

For more details, you can check the official document about [Using Android Assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-assets?tabs=windows).

In addition, you can also put the file in the share project setting Build Action to Embedded Resource. For more details, you can refer to the accpeted answer in this case about [Play .wav audio in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65657125/play-wav-audio-in-xamarin).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65657125/play-wav-audio-in-xamarin
I followed this and it works. Thank you very much. @Liyun Zhang - MSFT

Comment: You are welcome, glad to know your problem is resolved. Happy coding! @MertAltiparmak